# Не работает калькулятор из подключённых файлов

Tags: php

Почему не выводит результат? И ошибки не пишет.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Массивы</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='calc.php' method='post'>
        <input type='number' name='x'>
        <select name='op'>
            <option value='+'>+</option>
            <option value='-'>-</option>
            <option value='*'>*</option>
            <option value='/'>/</option>
        </select>
        <input type='number' name='y'>
        <input type='submit' value='='>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**handler.php**

```
<?php

function calc($a, $b, $op){
    switch ($op){
        case '+':
            return $a + $b;
            break;
        case '-':
            return $a - $b;
            break;
        case '*':
            return $a * $b;
            break;

        case '/':
            return $a / $b;
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

assert(4==calc(2,2, '+'));
assert(6==calc(2,3, '*'));
assert(3==calc(5,2, '-'));
?>
```

**calc.php**

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/handler.php';


$res = calc($_POST['x'], $POST['y'], $POST['op']);

echo $res;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

у вас ошибка с переменными $POST['y'], $POST['op'] - пропущено подчеркивание, а т.к. в самом скрипте по умолчанию операции выдается "null", то в результате ошибки нет, но и выводить ничего не нужно. т.е скорее всего пустой экран